# django not finding redirect page

Tags: django, django-views

hey guys i have the following codes, I'm trying to redirect the GoalUpdate view to GoalPageView , but I get the following Error:

Reverse for 'Goals.views.GoalPageView' with keyword arguments '{'kwargs': {'username': 'admin', 'goal_id': '1'}}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['people/(?P[^/]+)/goals/(?P<goal_id>[^/]+)/\Z']

**My URLs**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<username>/goals/',GoalsView,name='Goals'),
    path('<username>/goals/<goal_id>/',GoalPageView,name='Goal Page'),
    path('<username>/goals/<goal_id>/update/',GoalUpdate,name='Goal Update'),
                ]
```

**My Views:**

```
def GoalPageView(request,username,goal_id):

    some view code

    return render(request,'goal_page.html',context=context)



def GoalUpdate(request,username,goal_id):

    Some View Code
    
    return redirect(GoalPageView,kwargs={'username':username,'goal_id':goal_id})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`redirect` does not take `args` and `kwargs` but uses positional and named parameters directly, so:

```
def GoalUpdate(request, username, goal_id):
    # some view code …
    return redirect('Goal Page', username=username, goal_id=goal_id)
```

---

> **Note**: Functions are normally written in *snake_case*, not *PascalCase*, therefore it is
> advisable to rename your function to `goal_update`, not <s>`GoalUpdate`</s>.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `name` of url, not the `View` itself. To add `kwargs` like you can use `reverse_lazy`:

```
return redirect(reverse_lazy('Goal Page', kwargs={'username':username, 'goal_id':goal_id}))
```

But I think Willem gave you simpler solution.